# How to calculate XOR with offset?

Tags: ruby

I want to do a XOR calculation with different offset to list in calculation.

Example :

```
key = [0, 1, 0]
text = ["0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1"]
```

the XOR calculation:

```
key[0] ^ text[0] ; 
key[1] ^ text[1] ; 
key[2] ^ text[2] ; 
key[0] ^ text[3] ; 
key[1] ^ text[4] ; 
key[2] ^ text[5] ; 
key[0] ^ text[6] ; 
key[1] ^ text[7] ; 
key[2] ^ text[8] ;
key[0] ^ text[9] ;
```

How to do this ?

Comment: Ps. "calcul" is not a "word".

Comment: text contains an array of strings and not integers?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array#cycle` method to "cycle" your key as much as needed:

```
text.zip(key.cycle).map{|t,k| t.to_i ^ k}
# => [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Zipping a cycled array is always +1

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 1.9 has .cycle:

```
key = [0, 1, 0]
text = ["0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1"]
key_looper = key.cycle
p text.map{|el|key_looper.next ^ el.to_i} #=> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```