# Resolv an error

Tags: ruby

```
a = [1,0,1]
b = [101101, 0101100, 1011001101, 11000111, 1010110]
i = 0
j = 0
c = []
x = 0
d = []

while x < 5
  c.push b[i].to_s.split('')
  p c
  x = x +1
end

while i < 5
  e = c[i].length
  e = e + 1
  while j < e
    d[i][j] = a[i][j % 3] ^ b[i][j]
    puts d
    j = j + 1
  end
  i = i + 1
end


==> Resolv error line : d[i][j] = a[i][j % 3] ^ b[i][j]
====>  __.rb:18: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I not see ..

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate XOR with offset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961720/how-to-calculate-xor-with-offset)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `d[i][j]` you should create the 2 dimension:

```
...
d[i] = []
while j < e
  d[i][j] = a[i][j % 3] ^ b[i][j]
  puts d
  j = j + 1
end
...
```

but it's a strange code anyway. Why are you using `a[i][j % 3]` if `a` is a one-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `d` has only one dimension and in second `while` you're trying to assign two dimension value - `d[i][j]`. To resolve this issue put additional string to the while:

```
d[i] |= []
while j < e
    d[i][j] = a[i][j % 3] ^ b[i][j]
    puts d
    j = j + 1
  end
```