# XOR two strings

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xor of string in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348991/xor-of-string-in-ruby)

I would like to make a XOR calculation between two strings.

```
irb(main):011:0> a = 11110000
=> 11110000
irb(main):014:0> b = 10111100
=> 10111100
irb(main):015:0> a ^ b
=> 3395084
```

I would like to do this: `"hello" ^ "key"`

Comment: check this out [Xor of string in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/348991/49186)

Comment: you must learn how to use SO. You've been sending lots of questions which basically are the same (XOR and more XOR), but you don't comment on the answers, you don't select them, you give no feedback. What's the problem? For example, here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961720/how-to-calculate-xor-with-offset), you have this problem almost solved, just get the bytes of each string instead of using integers 0/1.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question ([348991](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348991/xor-of-string-in-ruby)) but of another one ([5961720](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961720/how-to-calculate-xor-with-offset))

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicate of either question: the first question (348991) was very poorly worded and the second (5961720) is a different use case.

Answer (score 14):

```
class String
  def ^( other )
    b1 = self.unpack("U*")
    b2 = other.unpack("U*")
    longest = [b1.length,b2.length].max
    b1 = [0]*(longest-b1.length) + b1
    b2 = [0]*(longest-b2.length) + b2
    b1.zip(b2).map{ |a,b| a^b }.pack("U*")
  end
end

p "hello" ^ "key"
#=> "he\a\t\u0016"
```

If this isn't the result you want, then you need to be explicit about how you want to perform the calculation, or what result you expect.

Answer (score 2):

1. convert both strings to byte arrays (take care with the character encoding, not everything can be represented with ASCII)
2. pad the shorter array with zeroes, so that they're both same size
3. for n from 0 to array size: XOR firstarray[n] with secondarray[n], probably store the result to result array
4. convert result byte array back into a string